# Conversations don't go to done despite setting a primary receiver and taking thread control

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

My facebook app has been set as the primary receiver of my facebook page. New conversations are supposed to be handled by the bot and are handed over to a human agent later, but my conversations always stay in main.

When I try to send a test webhook event of type messaging_handovers from the app options, I get this.

[image]

All in all, facebook messenger handovers aren't working as expected. I can find a lot of tutorials online but they seem to refer to an older implementation of handovers where you can set both primary receivers and secondary receviers.